# GetElementByTagName does not work on Sharepoint 2013 after update

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, sharepoint-2013

since I´ve updated to Sharepoint 2013 my Script does not generate any forms anymore. I'am using a function to load a XML file

```
function LoadXMLfromSP(xmlfile){

      var xml = $.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        url: xmlfile,
        dataType: "xml",
        async:false,



      }).responseText;
      xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml)

      return xmlDoc;

}

xmldoc = LoadXMLfromSP('https://mysite.de/form.xml');
```

console.log shows me that the xml object were sucessfully loaded but if i try

```
var obj = xmlobject.getElementsByTagName(node);
```

I got the message that this object does not support "GetElementsByTagName".
I tried anything at least deleting whitespaces in the xmldoc but the problem still exists.

As already mentioned: Before updating to Sharepoint 2013 everything worked perfectly (with IE, except Firefox and Chrome where I already experinced this issue before the Sharepoint update). But now, no matter which browser i use i got this error message and my script stops.

I hope that anyone can give me a hint or point me in the right direction to fix this issue. Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: You'll need to do more debugging. [`XMLDocument` instances](https://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#document) definitely have `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: Separately: The day is going to come when synchronous ajax requests won't work anymore. I suggest preparing for that day.

Comment: @Crowder Thank you for your quick answer. Will do more debugging but honestly I got the feeling that this issue relates to the SharePoint update and not to my script. Thanks for the hint with ajax.